# Align ImageView to right of it`s parent layout which is LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to align a ImageView to right(End) side of it`s parent layout, Which is compulsory LinearLayout. It is also not recommended to use RelativeLayout anywhere. As shown in below Image, the highlighted image should be right side of the screen. And without using RelativeLayout. Thanks in Advance.

[image: Image Here]

Below is My Activity_Main.xml code

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4"
    tools:context="com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_back_description"
            android:src="@drawable/back_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_app_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/txt_app_name" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_menu_description"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_icon" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_to_be_zoomed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/img" >
        </com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView>

        <com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_to_be_zoomed_mirror"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/img" >
        </com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/txt_view_top" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_gallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_label_gallery" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Oopps....sorry...my mistake...forgot to post....@NileshJarad

Comment: place empty view with weight=1 between your textView and imageView. Anyway, that's ugly workaround, and you should use RelativeLayout as it was created for this purposes

Comment: You right but, I`m in training and want to do exp. as well as my senior not allowed me to use relative layout. And I have researched on google but not find any solutions. So, I have to put question here.@VladMatvienko

Comment: I have posted answer and it's working please check it

Comment: It seems that you're trying to create a Toolbar, why don't you just use the actual Toolbar https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html ?

Comment: Yup, I am creating. But do not know about the actual toolbar as I am newbie to Android. Thank you very much for informing.@Budius

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this way and change as you want to put that.
change in `layout_weight` until you not get which you want. i hope this will help u more.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_back_description"
        android:src="@drawable/back_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_app_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/txt_app_name" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_menu_description"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_icon" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Happy Codeing

Comment: That`s a perfect answer, Bro!!@Jaydip

Comment: This is not the right answer @MaulikM.Dodia: the setted weight of the views divides the horizontal space for the three views, respectively of 25%, 50%, 25%. Maybe for you is however good, but it is not the answer to your question.

Comment: I am newbie to Android and your answer is perfect too but the both answers provide me desire result as well as I can not see any path to that answers. As I know, You have to give layout_weight to each of LinearLayouts` children if you specifying weigh to any child. So, I have accepted Jaydip`s answer.@Joseph82

Comment: No problem @MaulikM.Dodia, I was just saying that this answer addresses a slightly different question from your ;)

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that you have in the horizontal layout three view (ImageView, TextView, ImageView), you can use the following code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="prova"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/three_dots"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert an invisible View right before your ImageView in LinearLayout that will take all available space like this:

```
<View
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="1dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Comment: It`s just like a patch, not a real solution dude.@azertiti

Comment: If he wants to use LinearLayout and the TextView to have a pressed state it's probably the most reasonable one. Other options would be to make TextView take the whole space but this would be reflected when pressing it or make the ImageView take the space where you can run into trouble with scaling it. Given the disadvantages of those 2 solutions I'd go for the invisible view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4"
    tools:context="com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_back_description"
            android:src="@drawable/back_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_app_name"
            android:layout_width="match_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/menu_icon"
            android:text="@string/txt_app_name" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_to_be_zoomed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/img" >
        </com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView>

        <com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_to_be_zoomed_mirror"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/img" >
        </com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/txt_view_top" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_gallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_label_gallery" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It`s not producing desire result. Did you check it?@Kinnar Vasa

Comment: Seems fine to me, I have added dummy image as checkbox with tick: http://s9.postimg.org/dxdlxnsy7/Screen_Shot_2015_07_14_at_6_16_21_pm.png

Comment: You can not merge the App Name and Menu icon. This not desirable. This is looking like a patch work.@Kinnar Vasa

Comment: It is default android api, not patch: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableRight

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code. Just change your `textview` `txt_app_name` with the following code.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_app_name"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txt_app_name" />
```

Comment: It`s says Nested weights are bad for performance. Your solution is working, but giving that warning. Is it bad?@Bunny

Comment: Remove the weight from parent `LinearLayout`

Comment: Other thing you can do is: add another `LInearLayout` aroung your three views.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="4"
tools:context="com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_back_description"
        android:src="@drawable/back_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_app_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txt_app_name" />
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right">
               <ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/img_menu"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:contentDescription="@string/img_menu_description"
                  android:src="@drawable/menu_icon" />
       </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_to_be_zoomed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/img" >
    </com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView>

    <com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_to_be_zoomed_mirror"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/img" >
    </com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/txt_view_top" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_gallery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_label_gallery" />
</LinearLayout>
```